# APC advice for not having persistent data

Tags: php, variables, caching, apc

I've installed APC on my server to improve performance since i have too many db queries executing. So I've set variable in apc_store('example','333',600) (this should be 600 seconds) and I can see that it is working sporadically. Meaning sometimes it does and sometimes it doesnt show me files from cache. I've informed a little and found out that it is due some mmap or FastCGI (im not that familiar with that field).
How can this be handled, and what are benefits/consequences ?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to give more detail on how it is configured and how it is failing for us to be able to give you any really useful answers

Comment: Well, I on dedicated hosting plan, and I paid for APC implementation. After it has been enabled, I tried a simplest code and it sometimes reads from cached variable and sometimes don't (rather dont than do). They told me it is due to different processes that are being assigned and only when i hit the same process it will find the variable in cache. On my request to enable me constant caching they said they will have to turn off something called mmap. Im just wondering if it will have some downsides if i accept it..?